# aggregate multiple columns in spark window function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying aggregation for multiple columns. Here is my scenario.

I have a columns like this TagID,ListnerID,Timestamp and RSSI_weightage.

I want to select the highest rssi_weightage's for each TagID. And Also I need to pick the hightest Timestamp for the above association.

Example.

```
TagID,ListnerID,Timestamp,RSSI_Weightage
2,101,1496745906,90
3,102,1496745907,70
3,104,1496745906,80
2,101,1496745909,60
4,106,1496745908,60

My expected output

2,101,1496745909,90
3,104,1496745907,80
4,106,1496745908,60
```

Explanation

For TagID 2 the highest rssi_weighatge is 90.But the latest timestamp is 1496745909.That is my first row .Same thing I did for all tagID's.

The above is my expected output. I tried like this.

```
val window = Window.partitionBy("tagShortID", "ListenerShortID").orderBy("RSSI_Weightage","Timestamp")
 val prox = averageDF.withColumn("rank", row_number().over(window)).where($"rank" === 1)
```

But the above statement not works properly. I am getting incorrect results.Also If I apply desc in order by, It throws error.

Comment: What you describe and your expected output dont match

Comment: Okay Might be I described wrongly.But My expected output is correct one.

Comment: for the highest `RSSI_weightage` the timestamp is `1496745906`. where did that go in your expected result? I don't get what you are doing with your timestamps.

Comment: Thats the logic. If I get highest Rssi_weighatge,Then also I need to check for latest timestamp for the association

Comment: Thats why I mentioned 1496745909 timestamp on first row

Comment: `.orderBy(desc("RSSI_Weight_avg"))`. Where did RSSI_Weightage = 70 go?

Comment: No the query is wrong.I am trying to achieve my expected result. I need suggestion for the exact query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the dataframe as

```
+----------+---------------+----------+---------------+
|tagShortID|ListenerShortID|Timestamp |RSSI_Weight_avg|
+----------+---------------+----------+---------------+
|2         |101            |1496745906|90             |
|3         |102            |1496745907|70             |
|3         |104            |1496745906|80             |
|2         |101            |1496745909|60             |
|4         |106            |1496745908|60             |
+----------+---------------+----------+---------------+
```

You can do the following with `Window` function. But you will have to do some additional tasks like `filter` and `drop`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val window = Window.partitionBy($"tagShortID")
val prox = averageDF.withColumn("RSSI_Weight_avg", max($"RSSI_Weight_avg").over(window))
  .withColumn("rank", rank().over(window.orderBy($"Timestamp".desc)))
  .filter($"rank" === 1)
  .drop("rank")
```

You will get result as

```
+----------+---------------+----------+---------------+
|tagShortID|ListenerShortID|Timestamp |RSSI_Weight_avg|
+----------+---------------+----------+---------------+
|3         |102            |1496745907|80             |
|4         |106            |1496745908|60             |
|2         |101            |1496745909|90             |
+----------+---------------+----------+---------------+
```

You can impove the above code though. I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Is It possible to group by two columns like I need tagID and Listner ID

Comment: If you do that you won't be getting your expected result

Comment: Oh okay Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: my pleasure :) @Jessijoseph